# Longtable with numbered list without using preset counter names

Tags: tables, longtable, enumerate, counters

I am trying to make a longtable to list out publications but I want to use arabic numerals combined with latin capital letters for different categories. This is what I have for only a few items, but I would like to keep updating this so that the newer entries are first and it will be tedious to keep adding them by hand when the numbers get larger.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%http://www.procato.com/rgbfind/
\definecolor{navy_blue}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.502}

\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{longtable}{@{} p{.3in} l}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textcolor{navy_blue}{\Large{\textbf{Publications}}}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\Large{\underline{Journal Articles}}} \\

(J1) & \parbox{6.2in}{\large{\textbf{Author 1}, Author 2 (year). Title. \textit{Journal} \\
(J2) & \parbox{6.2in}{\large{\textbf{Author 1}, Author 2, Author 3 (year). Title. \textit{Journal} \\

\multicolumn{2}{l}{\Large{\underline{Conference Abstracts with Presentations}}} \\

(A1) & \parbox{6.2in}{\large{\textbf{Author 1}, Author 2 (year). Title. \textit{Conference} \\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I think I can include an enumerate in place of (J1), (J2), etc., but I'm not clear how to make these specific numbering styles. I've tried following the documentation on Overleaf to at least get some basic numbering to work but I'm getting an error. **This MWE below is just my effort to get some numbers going, and is not an effort to get the numbering style working yet.**

```
\noindent \begin{longtable}{@{} p{.3in} l}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textcolor{navy_blue}{\Large{\textbf{Publications}}}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\Large{\underline{Journal Articles}}} \\

\begin{enumerate}

\item & \parbox{6.2in}{\large{\textbf{Author 1}, Author 2 (year). Title. \textit{Journal} \\
    
\end{enumerate}

\end{longtable}
```

The error says that `\item` is missing but it's not and that there might be some extra `}` in my code.

Comment: Do you really need a long table for that? Sections and different kinds of enumerate environments would be simpler to implement, methinks.

Comment: Yes, the longtable is meant to continue from page to page and will eventually be populated with 20+ items in multiple categories.

Comment: You wouldn't group the items by categories?

Comment: They already are grouped by category.

Comment: Why a table then? (Also beware a table can break  across pages only between rows, not inside a row).

Comment: The table is the best way of organizing things like CV's based on my experience. Breaking between rows is exactly what I want.

Comment: In this case, a single  column would  do the trick. Why a special column for the item label?

Comment: Because then I have to keep adding new entries by hand manually each time. I don't want to do that. I want to add in the publication details and have the enumeration update somewhat automatically. I believe I wrote that out in my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120141/discussion-between-bernard-and-wngatrc456).